# is it worth tracking down memory or thread leaks when re-starting the server every few hours just works?

Tags: multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, thread-safety

This is a common problem I've found in many large projects:

1. It runs fine in development because you are always stopping and re-starting the server
2. After it runs in production for many hours, a memory or thread issue is revealed.

A very easy production solution is to just kill and restart the process every few hours.

If that works 100% of the time, and trying to get the program to run for hours (days) without this problem is very hard, why spend engineering resources to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If that works 100% of the time, and trying to get the program to run for hours (days) without this problem is very hard, why spend engineering resources to solve the problem?

Sorry I missed the entire point of this question initially.  I'd say yes it does matter because of the following:

1. Programmers copy code all of the time.  You may have bad patterns or libraries running in your server that are propagating into other parts of your system right now.
2. If this is a service that is required to scale, it may come a point when you need to restart it every 30 minutes, then 20, and then all of the time.  When this point comes you will most likely be under the gun without the engineering time to actually find and fix the problem.  Vertical scaling to a larger box is then your own opportunity.
3. In general your engineering team may learn something from the exercise.  In general you should be up to date on how to diagnose these problems -- especially running profilers and leak detectors.
4. If this product is currently under development then it's *very* hard to forecast whether or not the next feature will change the memory curve and make this problem worse.  Then your feet will be in the fire to fix the problem before you can push the next release.

If, however, this is some low use product in maintenance mode then its probably fine to not dedicate any resources to fixing it -- but not optimal.

---

In terms of figuring out whether it is a leak in the threads or the memory, it really depends on what you are running out of.  If you do a `ps` and see that it is forking a ton of threads and *that* is why you are running out of memory (because of the stacks) then you will have to tackle that problem.

If the number of threads that are being spawned seems to be relatively stable but the memory is continuing to increase then memory leaks are what you need to concentrate on.

If you are on linux, you can see the thread process-ids with `ps auxf`:

```
root      2501  0.0  0.3 244448 25576 ?    Ss   Jul03   0:11 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2716  0.0  0.5 384776 46696 ?    S    Oct14   0:17  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2717  0.0  0.5 382208 44304 ?    S    Oct14   0:11  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Either the number of child threads is growing or the `ps` will show that the virtual memory of the process is increasing until it swaps or hits some `ulimit` but the threads are relatively constant.

Comment: sure that gets into how to debug the real problem, but my question is why?  if just re-starting the servers gives you a clean state, why not just do that and ignore all the details above?

Comment: wow, great answer.  I was going to ask my boss, why spend time doing this and now I don't have to.